# SQL, query to check and list distinct entries that occur in another table within a specific time frame

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle.

I have two tables. One contains users and the other is an access log of sorts. I need to list all users whose latest log entry appears in the log within a specified time frame including the timestamp of the latest entry. A single user can have several entries in the log.

Here are simplified versions of the tables:

Users

```
|----------------------------------|
| userid| username | name          |
|----------------------------------|
| 1     | josm     | John Smith    |
| 2     | lajo     | Laura Jones   |
| 3     | miwi     | Mike Williams |
| 4     | subo     | Susan Brown   |
| 5     | peda     | Peter Davis   |
| 6     | jami     | Jane Miller   |
|----------------------------------|
```

Log

```
|----------------------------------|
| userid| action   | timestamp     |
|----------------------------------|
| 3     | a        | 20-01-2020    |
| 2     | v        | 19-11-2019    |
| 2     | y        | 02-11-2019    |
| 4     | b        | 15-09-2019    |
| 1     | a        | 23-05-2019    |
| 6     | y        | 22-05-2019    |
| 3     | b        | 16-04-2019    |
| 2     | a        | 07-01-2019    |
| 5     | v        | 18-11-2018    |
| 6     | a        | 12-09-2018    |
|----------------------------------|
```

Desired result if the time frame is set to last six months:

```
|---------------------------------------|
| username | name          | timestamp  |
|--------------------------|------------|
| miwi     | Mike Williams | 20-01-2020 |
| lajo     | Laura Jones   | 19-11-2019 |
| subo     | Susan Brown   | 15-09-2019 |
|---------------------------------------|
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"whose latest log entry appears in the log within a specified time frame"* So, if a user's latest entry is not in the time frame, you don't want to show them? E.g. time span 2019-01-01 to 2019-06-30. lajo's latest entry is 2019-11-19, which is not inside the frame. Hence you would not show lajo in your results. Correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Users whose latest entry is not within the time frame would be omitted from the result.

Comment: Then Gordon's answer should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select u.username, u.userid, max(l.timestamp)
from logs l join
     users u
     on l.userid = u.userid
group by u.username, u.userid
having max(l.timestamp) >= add_months(sysdate, -6)
```